# How to skip reviewer for project administrator pull request?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is it possible to configure the repository to skip "At least one reviewer must approve the most recent iteration" in case the person who performs the Pull request is the project administrator?

I have the below branch Policy:

[image]

I made the review approbation for my own commit.

[image]

But when I'm going to complete the pull request, I get the below message:

[image]

> At least one reviewer must approve the most recent iteration.

It's possible to skip review requirement only for project administrators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can add "bypass policies" for project admins.

[image]

The documentation: [Security groups - Git repository (object-level)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#git-repository-object-level)

Comment: That made the trick, a new option appears at the end: "Override branch policies and enable merge".

Comment: This solution allows the author to also bypass policies such as unresolved comments and failing builds.